# How to parse numbers fields in excel file by using xlsx npm package(node js)

Tags: node.js, xlsx

[image]

I have some excel xls file . I want to parse it by using `xlsx package` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) .. I read a file by `multer`  and get some `req.file.buffer` response and try to parse this response in this way .

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');
let x = xlsx.read(req.file.buffer, {type:"buffer"});
```

when u will make request like `console.log(x.Strings);` u will get smth like this :

```
[ { t: 'first_name', raw: '<t>first_name</t>', r: 'first_name' },
  { t: 'middle_name', raw: '<t>middle_name</t>', r: 'middle_name' },
  { t: 'last_name', raw: '<t>last_name</t>', r: 'last_name' },
  { t: 'phone_number_first',
    raw: '<t>phone_number_first</t>',
    r: 'phone_number_first' },
  { t: 'phone_number_second',
    raw: '<t>phone_number_second</t>',
    r: 'phone_number_second' },
  { t: 'email', raw: '<t>email</t>', r: 'email' },
  { t: 'address1', raw: '<t>address1</t>', r: 'address1' },
  { t: 'address2', raw: '<t>address2</t>', r: 'address2' },
  { t: 'zipcode', raw: '<t>zipcode</t>', r: 'zipcode' },
  { t: 'city', raw: '<t>city</t>', r: 'city' },
  { t: 'state', raw: '<t>state</t>', r: 'state' },
  { t: 'fds', raw: '<t>fds</t>', r: 'fds' },
  { t: 'fsd', raw: '<t>fsd</t>', r: 'fsd' },
  { t: '[19674913171]',
    raw: '<t>[19674913171]</t>',
    r: '[19674913171]' },
  { t: 'fdssd@gmail.com',
    raw: '<t>fdssd@gmail.com</t>',
    r: 'fdssd@gmail.com' },
  { t: 'fdsfs', raw: '<t>fdsfs</t>', r: 'fdsfs' },
  Count: 44,
  Unique: 16 ]
```

Here u can see that number in pure form this library do not return .. Only when I add some characters in number field `[19674913171]` <-- smth like this , only then u will see this field .. How to configure it in the way when I don't need to add some characters and get response :

```
{ t: '19674913171',
    raw: '<t>19674913171</t>',
    r: '19674913171' }
```

Answer (score 12):

```
let wb= xlsx.read(file.buffer, {type: "buffer"});
const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
const data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_csv(ws);
```

Here is the answer .. Then u will get all fields

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! :-) Consider marking your answer as accepted so that other users can see that the problem was solved.

Comment: Getting nothing in data